# jQuery hide class instance based on .prev() height

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to hide a More/Less toggle bar based on the height of the adjacent (ie, just previous) .entry-text div. If .entry-text is taller than 265px, I want the More/Less toggle bar to appear. If .entry-text is smaller than 265px, I want to hide the toggle bar.

This is the relevant portion of js:

```
$(".show-more").filter(function () {
    return ($(this).prev().height() < 265);
}).hide();
```

And this is the HTML structure:

```
<div class="panel entry-content" id="tab-included">
    <div class="entry-text">
        <!-- Content goes here -->
    </div>
    <div class="show-more"> <a href="#">Show more</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I believe I actually have the code working in JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/ssnhy/1/), but it doesn't appear to work on my website. Take https://www.alangordon.com/sales/used/lenses/35mm/zooms/cooke-25-250mm-t3.9-zoom-lens for example: The Product Features tab clearly has content shorter than 265px and thus, the More/Less toggle bar is hidden. However, the What's Included tab has content taller than 265px, but the More/Less toggle bar is also hidden.

Thank you for reading!

EDIT: I think I've figured part of the problem. When the page loads, any tab that is not selected is returning a height of 0px, and as such the More/Less toggle is not being displayed. What I need to happen is have the code recheck the height of the .entry-text when the tab is selected to determine whether the .entry-text is tall enough.

Comment: you need to check for the height AFTER the content is shown, in other words, check the height and do your logic after the user has clicked the tab. The other thing you can do is - before hiding the tab content, check for the height and apply toggle, then hide the inactive tabs. However, I think it is better to check for height after they have been opened

Comment: This click handler e(".woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li a").click(function () {...} you can either fire an event after the active class is added then capture it as a custom event or call the check height function from there

Comment: use your filter code, when the tabs are clicked, as well as page load(for the first tab). Or hide the elements a different way, IE. z-index

Comment: Thanks @Huangism and @Rooster! I've managed to whip up an answer using your suggestions. Check out my solution below and feel free to offer any refactoring tips.

Answer (score 0):

**or run it as a function on visible tabs**

```
function sh() {
    $('.entry-text:visible').each(function() {//for each entry
        if ($(this).height()<265) {//if height less than 265
            $(this).siblings('.show-more').hide();//hide more
        }
    });
}
sh();//run on initial

$('.show-more a').on('click', function () {//for each more link
    $(this).text($(this).text()=='Show more'?'Show less':'Show more')//text
    .parent().prev('.entry-text').toggleClass('full-text');//class
    return false;
});

$('.tabs > li > a').on('click', function() { sh(); });//resize on new tab
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/Q7qH8/

Answer (score -1):

Here's what ended up working for me. I'm sure there's room for refactoring:

```
// Check height on the active tab
var $woo_tab_a_href = $('.woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li.active a').attr('href');
$('div' + $woo_tab_a_href + " .show-more").filter(function () {
  return ($(this).prev(".entry-text").height() < 265);
}).hide();

// Check height on any tab that is clicked
$('.woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li a').click(function(){
    var $tab = $(this);
    $('div' + $tab.attr('href') + " .show-more").filter(function () {
      return ($(this).prev(".entry-text").height() < 265);
    }).hide();
});
```

Comment: You're basically doing the same thing twice, and `.woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li a` selects all `a` inside of `.tabs li` which would include `.show-more`. If you focus on `.entry-text` that are `:visible`, you can make this one function, and target tab's links with something more like `.tabs > li > a` then it will select the proper links for tab switching.